# If I am using a VPN, what does the website or app (like Netflix) see when I am downloading or uploading?

Tags: privacy, vpn

If I am using a VPN, what does the website or app (like Netflix) see when I am downloading or uploading?

For example, if I upload an image, will they see that I am uploading from VPN's IP or my IP?

Answer (score 2):

If all your traffic is routed through your VPN, then everyone will see the public IP for your VPN's outgoing interface.

[image: VPN Traffic diagram (simplified)]

Comment: Additionally, some sites like Netflix keep a list of known VPN IP's and will prevent connections from them. So you need a VPN provider that shifts IPs to keep the ability to use Netflix while connected tot he VPN. 

If you are hosting your own VPN server though, likely that wont be a concern.